# Why is my NSInteger changing from 12345 to -1758050543 when I pass it as an argument in an Obj-C method call?

Tags: objective-c, parameters, arguments, nslog

Here's the code in AlertTableView:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    NSInteger index = 12345;
    NSLog(@"AlertTableView: selecting row at index %d", index);
    [self.caller didSelectRowAtIndex:index withContext:self.context];
}
```

In self.caller:

```
- (void)didSelectRowAtIndex:(NSInteger)row withContext:(id)context {
    NSLog(@"Selected row at index %d with context %@", index, context);
}
```

Console output:

```
2009-05-07 15:51:30.619 Whiteboard[15165:20b] AlertTableView: selecting row at index 12345
2009-05-07 15:51:30.620 Whiteboard[15165:20b] Selected row at index -1758050543 with context <Picker: 0x587c20>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't look like you have "index" in scope in your method, try this:

```
- (void)didSelectRowAtIndex:(NSInteger)row withContext:(id)context {
  NSLog(@"Selected row at index %d with context %@", row, context);
}
```

Just looks like a typo :)